# JOIN overwriting when multiple columns have the same ID in SQL

Tags: sql, count, left-join

I am left joining a table to another table in SQL, but the second table has multiple cases with the same ID and when I join the tables together while matching with ID, only the last case with the matching ID is appended.  What I would prefer to happen is that SQL count the amount of times something matches ID and then creates a count as well as the individual cases.

TABLE 1:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ab |
| 2 | sd |
| 3 | oh |
| 4 | sd |
| 5 | as |

TABLE 2:

| ID | pet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat |
| 1 | dog |
| 2 | fish |
| 3 | dog |
| 5 | cat |
| 5 | cat |

Expected Output:

| ID | val | count_pets | cat | dog | fish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ab | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | sd | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | oh | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | sd | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | as | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Currently my code looks like:

```
SELECT
    t1.*, t2.*
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT Table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

which results in

| ID | value | pet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ab | dog |
| 2 | sd | fish |
| 3 | oh | dog |
| 4 | sd | NA |
| 5 | as | cat |

How do I get those count columns instead?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

You are "pivoting" the result of the join. You can use conditional aggregation to produce those extra columns.

For example:

```
select
  a.id,
  max(a.value) as val,
  count(*) as count_pets,
  sum(case when b.pet = 'cat' then 1 else 0 end) as cat,
  sum(case when b.pet = 'dog' then 1 else 0 end) as dog,
  sum(case when b.pet = 'fish' then 1 else 0 end) as fish
from table1 a
left join table2 b on b.id = a.id
group by a.id
```